# add a meta value to the shortcode twice

Tags: shortcode, post-meta

I would like to build a shortcode looks like below.

```
[employee_session trigger=session-popup-1 trigger_type=id in_dialog=1 employee=1]
[employee_session trigger=session-popup-2 trigger_type=id in_dialog=1 employee=2]
[employee_session trigger=session-popup-3 trigger_type=id in_dialog=1 employee=3]
```

...

session-popup-1,2,3 & employee=1,2,3 are dynamic meta data which represents employee_id

so it's gonna be

```
[employee_session trigger=session-popup-"employee_id" trigger_type=id in_dialog=1 employee="employee_id"]
```

I can get the employee_id meta value using another shortcode but I can't have both working within a single shortcode..

Can you advise me to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the shortcode in content, or in a template file?

Comment: in a template file

Comment: Did you possibly mean to write `do_shortcode( '[employee_session trigger="session-popup-' . $employee_id . '" trigger_type="id" in_dialog=1 employee=' . $employee_id . ']' );`? What you have there is not proper shortcode syntax.

Comment: Yes, you are right that it's not proper one. I was just showing that was the outcome of the shortcodes, which I couldn't figure out how to make the shorcode such way. You seem to have one. I shall try it and get back to you. Thx!

Comment: it works! I added it to a snippet and wrap up with another shortcode and add the new shortcode into the template! it works like a charm! Thank you for your help!

Comment: I can't choose your comment as an anwer, you can post it rather than adding a comment. :-)